# RuntimeError using ASP's PageMethods

Tags: javascript, asp.net

code in my aspx is like:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Services" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var validate = function() {
        PageMethods.Send_Mail(OnSuccess, OnFailure);
    };

    function OnSuccess(result) {
        alert(result);
    };

    function OnFailure(error) {
        alert(error);
    };

</script>

<script runat="server">

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static String Send_Mail()
    {   
       //do Something
    }
</script>

<body>
<form>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"></asp:ScriptManager>
</form>
</body>
```

I get an RuntimeError because of the static modifier in "public static String..", when I remove static the page is shown correctly but Send_Mail() is never called. (surprisingly..)

I guess System.Web.Services.WebMethod is not imported correctly,
so I tried to find out how to / if i need to add assembly in web.config, unfortunately I couldn't find an example how to add it to web.config correctly.

Any idea?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Why are you writing new page/web methods in 2019? Create an ASP.NET Web API, then call it via AJAX.

Comment: It's an pretty outdated Website from a customer.